# Angular set datetime to localtime

Tags: angular

I have a problem with the DateTime.

```
let date = this.datepipe.transform(this.productForm.value.start_at, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss');
console.log(date);

result will always show as 2020-05-02 12:00:00
```

The DateTime suppose to show my current time instead of always shows `12:00:00`. My timezone is Asia/Tokyo

Comment: How is the `this.productForm.value.start` value at looks like?

Comment: @yazantahhan is `2020-05-02` without time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create new Date and set the year, month and date.

```
const [year, month, day] = this.productForm.value.start_at.split("-");
const currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setDate(+day);
currentDate.setFullYear(+year);
currentDate.setMonth(+month - 1);
const formattedDate = this.datepipe.transform(currentDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss');
```

You can achieve the same thing if too you created `new Date(this.productForm.value.start_at)` and use getDate, getFullYear and getMonth instead of the split.

Answer (score 0):

Have added +0900 as you are in Tokyo and considering GMT as +0900

```
 import {formatDate } from '@angular/common';


    let date = new Date();
    const localDate = formatDate(date, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a', 'en-US', '+0900');
    console.log(localDate);
```

Comment: While this will work for in this case (Tokyo), it won't work for other countries that has daylight savings, and it won't set the hours, minutes and seconds